# Firebug show import statements are loaded twice

Tags: php, firefox, firebug

I have few import statements in my index.php file. The website is bit slow so I trying to debug it. When I first load the page firebug shows that it's loading the import statements twice. The second 'copy' so to say is still loading(it has the dynamic indicator that it's loading). I am using Net in firebug to see the results.

In chrome however it only shows once. I have the latest stable version 1.7.3 and I am using firefox 5.

Index.php has two `include_once` statement. First includes file has the database connections and few import statements. Second one has the header(Simple HTML statements - nothing fancy).

It is a firebug issue or something on my end?

Index.php

```
<htmL>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php

include_once('db_con.php');
include_once('header.php');

?>

<div id="displayAjax"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

db_con.php

```
<?php
$host="host";
$username="user";
$password="pass";
$database="dbname";

$table1="table1";
$table2="table2";
$table2="table3"; 

$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
$select_db = mysql_select_db("$database")or die("cannot select DB");

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

session_start(); 
?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="import/file.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="import/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="import/ajax.js"></script>

</head>
</html>
```

header.php

```
<?php
include_once('db_con.php');
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p>Title</p>


Search for: 
<input type="textbox" size="27" id="id" class="class" />
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchFunction()" />
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

So I created a new file new.html. Only HTML syntax, no PHP or JS.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>Something</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I went to the link directly no includes or imports. This one still loads twice. First one is loaded and it displays 'Something' second one is still loading with dynamic indicator.

Comment: show us some code please

Comment: So in other words your web page gets called twice by Firefox?

Comment: @Adrian yea the web page is getting called twice.

Comment: There are a lot of things I have found about Firefox calling a page twice. Looking at your code I only spot what Tomalak says in his answer about duplicate full html pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all your includes are resolved, you have two full HTML documents. What the browser decides to do with the resulting invalid document is up to the browser.

Take that HTML out of `db_con.php`; it has nothing to do with database connections.

Comment: i did try that. i put the import statements in the header file but it does the same thing. The html statements has nothing to do with db but I am trying to cheat a bit here as the header is not imported across the website but the db_con is.

Comment: @daking963: That's a ghastly thing to do. It will be (and, possibly, _has been_) your undoing. The fact that you actually knew this but decided to do it anyway is distressing.

Comment: @Tomalok Just to get test it out I took your advice and changed it. All the HTML import statements are in header.html file. It still doesn't solve my problem. It still loads it twice. Any other insights? So in essence there is only one HTML file now.

Comment: @daking963: Let's see a testcase that has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: @Tomalok Updated the question. It's the same thing, it still loads twice. I am leaning towards a firebug issue.

Comment: Ok it's definitely a firebug issue. It loads every site twice(Tried google.com). Not sure why i didn't try that first. Need a break.

Comment: @daking963: That doesn't make it "definitely a firebug issue", only not localised to your HTML page.